# Entity Framework / SQL Server Include behaviour with filtering

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have two basic questions regarding EF and SQL Server which I will ask along with examples.

1. Say I have the following query:

   ```
   db.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders)
           .Include(c => c.Items)
           .Include(....).Where(c => c.Age > 25)
   ```

   In this simple query I retrieve customers based on some condition and get some related data from other tables. Will the includes (joins) happen on all the records in the database first and then these will be filtered on the condition **or** first the engine will filter the records without joining anything and then perform joins only on the filtered records? This question concerns EF as far as what will be generated as a query maybe and the SQL Server query engine too.
2. What will be the behaviour if some of the properties used in the includes are part of the filtering? Will again **ALL** joins be performed on every record in the database **or** it will only perform the needed joins for filtering on all the records in the database and then do the remaining joins only on the filtered records? The situation can be described like:

   ```
   db.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders)
           .Include(c => c.Items)
           .Include(....).Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o.Name.StartsWith("Football")
   ```

   Also how the behaviour differs if no navigation properties are used in the filtering (as in question 1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Include will not filter related objects based on filters you provided. Because both are different operations. In that case you will have to use Projections.

```
db.Customers.Include(c => c.Orders)
    .Include(c => c.Items)
    .Include(....).Where(c => c.Orders.Any(o.Name.StartsWith("Football")
```

Above query will give different results then query with Projection as shown below,

```
db.Customers
    .Include(c => c.Items)
    .Include(....).Select(c => new {
         Customer = c,
         Orders = c.Orders.Where( o => o.Name.StartsWith("Football")
    })
```

I have removed Include for Orders, but I have created Projection for Orders.

In first case there will be no join for `WHERE` clause, but it will use `EXISTS` clause and for Include it will use Join to get all records.

In second case it will perform join to get results with filter, so it will only perform join on filter specified in projection.

Comment: I understand the difference. But the questions are different - I'm asking how will EF / SQL Server perform joining in different cases, not how to return certain results.

Comment: Thanks. Can you just clarify how it will use EXISTS in the first case - maybe to check if and ID is in the list of results specified by WHERE clause? Using EXISTS doesn't mean it will perform joins on the whole database, right? And for the second case it will first join only Orders in my case and then when the records are filtered it will perform the remaining joins on the filtered records, right?

Comment: ANY is replaced mostly with `EXISTS`, joins become too complicated to compute, as you may have many nested Any in query, so EF puts `EXISTS` which can be nested easily. Join is never performed on entire database, it is only performed on rows that match your WHERE filter. So even if EF is using EXISTS, it will only perform join on small subset that matches query.